# Sum certain groups of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where I want to sum the values between certain irregularly spaced dates.  So for example, I have something like this:

| date | widgets |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 1 |
| 2021-03-02 | 0 |
| 2021-03-03 | 1 |
| 2021-03-04 | 3 |
| 2021-03-05 | 1 |
| 2021-03-06 | 2 |

And I know that the cutoff dates for the sums are 2021-03-01, 2021-03-04, 2021-03-05 so that I want the sum of all widgets produced on the cutoff date and up to (but not including) the next cutoff date. All dates that are not cutoff dates would have a value of 0.

This would produce a new column like below.

| date | widgets | sums |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-03-02 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-03 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-03-04 | 3 | 3 |
| 2021-03-05 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-03-06 | 2 | 0 |

How can I do this within pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) #convert to datetime
```

---

Then check for occurance of cutoffs and cumsum and use them as grouper column:

```
cutoffs= ['2021-03-01', '2021-03-04', '2021-03-05']
cond = df['date'].isin(pd.to_datetime(cutoffs))
df['sums'] = df.groupby(cond.cumsum())['widgets'].transform('sum').where(cond,0)

print(df)

        date  widgets    sums
0 2021-03-01        1       2
1 2021-03-02        0       0
2 2021-03-03        1       0
3 2021-03-04        3       3
4 2021-03-05        1       3
5 2021-03-06        2       0
```